# Is onConstructor property of the Lombok's @[No|All|Required]ArgsConstructor annotation work Java 7 style only?

Tags: java, lombok

According to the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor), Lombok has 3 annotations for constructor generation:

- `@NoArgsConstructor` - generates an empty constructor;
- `@AllArgsConstructor` - generates a constructor that initializes all
  fields;
- `@RequiredArgsConstructor` - generates a constructor that
  initializes only `final` fields.

They all have an `onConstructor` property that allows you to specify the annotations with which the generated constructor should be marked.

According to the [Javadoc](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/2ac4faf14cfb4e82b771f8691704efd3c36299ea/src/core/lombok/NoArgsConstructor.java#L57), the syntax for this feature depends on JDK version (nothing we can do about that; it's to work around javac bugs).

Up to JDK7:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__({@AnnotationsGoHere}))
```

From JDK8:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(onConstructor_={@AnnotationsGohere}) // note the underscore after onConstructor
```

I am working on JDK8. However, only the JDK7 variant works for me, while the JDK8 variant does not work (a constructor without annotations is generated).

I checked on JDK11 - same result.

I check with *Refactor -> Delombok -> @Constructors*.

For example, like this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Deprecated))
public class SomeClass {
}
```

the following code is generated:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Deprecated
    public SomeClass() {
    }
}
```

But like so:

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Deprecated)
public class SomeClass {
}
```

code like this is generated:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass() {
    }
}
```

I noticed that the documentation on the Lombok site only contains a JDK7 style example.

The Javadoc is incorrect or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think StackOverflow isn't the best place for a questions like this. It would probably be much better to ask Lombok authors directly by creating an issue on their github page.

Comment: Both syntax work for me on both Java 8 and 11... I tested with `@Deprecated`. Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: OK, I've added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found, that it's not the Lombok's bug, it's [Lombok IntelliJ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/) bug.

Constructor annotations add in compiled code.

Delombok tool of Lombok IntelliJ plugin incorrect convert Lombok's annotations to vanilla Java code.